# How do i do run-time deploy ignite service of same name without restart the server node?

Tags: ignite

I have 3 ignite server node and several client node,

The ignite server use the official ignite package, and the client node code is written by myself and with custome service logic. I star the server first, and i activate the cluster, then i start the client, the service will pushed to remote server, but sometimes I have made some update to my customize service, and i want to deploy the new code to the remote ignite server? is there any way that i don't need restart my remote server node to update hte service, just do someting maybe like:
add the new jar to the server classpath, cancel the old service, start the new client with new service code to push the service to the remote  server?

is this possilbe? i have try to do this, but i found the service could not be updated, unless i restart the server with the new jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now this is not possible. You have to restart the Ignite instance to update service's implementation.

But hot redeployment is planned to be implemented soon. You will be able to configure a [DeploymentSpi](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/deployment-spi#section-deploymentspi) and use it to update services.
You can find details by the following links:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/IEP-17%3A+Oil+Change+in+Service+Grid#IEP-17:OilChangeinServiceGrid-Hotredeployment

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-8367

Comment: Thanks for the info, as restart is the only approach, the change including cache configurations(maybe key, value type changes, or value class stucture changes, or cache config changes), and the also the service realization, should i do some thing before the restart (beside replace the jar with new one), i have found sometimes i need remove the content in wiht "rm -fr /usr/com/apache-ignite and
rm -fr /usr/share/apache-ignite", but this cause i need totally re-deploy the whole cluster, not only restart the server node, what's the correct step for update the cache & service ?

Comment: If you have persistence enabled, then you will have to undeploy the service before changing its implementation. Because otherwise Ignite will attempt to redeploy old service using new class and fail during deserialization. And if you want to change cache configuration, then you will have to destroy this cache first. This is not deeded, if you want just to change key/value type unless you want to change structure of you values(number and names of fields).

Comment: So, for cache, if name not changed, it is possilbe to update the cache if it only change cache configuraion or the cache value (value is class) structure change(add/remove members or some fields name change) using the way of call cache destroy, then re-create it again, if the cache key, value type changes, i should better use a new name for this cache, as the type changes, it is totally a new cache, right?

Comment: If you perform destroy/create, then you are free to change cache configuration in any way you need.